# Auto landscape when the user click the full screen video using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i hope the title is enough to understand my problem is, ***story line***: When the user click full screen. the video automatic landscape. How? please help me

```
      Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl:
                      "https://ip-address/play.html?name=123456789",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller,
                      String url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onProgressChanged:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ])),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dependencies:   auto_orientation: ^2.0.0

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:auto_orientation/auto_orientation.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    AutoOrientationDemo(),
  );
}

class AutoOrientationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  AutoOrientationDemo({this.title = 'Auto Orientation Demo'});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AutoOrientationDemoState();
  }
}

class _AutoOrientationDemoState extends State<AutoOrientationDemo> {
  TargetPlatform? _platform;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.title,
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        platform: _platform ?? Theme.of(context).platform,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.portraitDownMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Portrait UPSIDE Down"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.fullAutoMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("All modes"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Landscape auto"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.portraitAutoMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Portrait auto"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.landscapeLeftMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Landscape left mode"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
                        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
                        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
                      ]);
                      AutoOrientation.landscapeRightMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Landscape right mode"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.portraitUpMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Portrait up mode"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      AutoOrientation.portraitDownMode();
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      child: Text("Portrait down mode"),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This Will Help You For Auto Screen Orientation based on your content

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript channel to get notifications from the web view. See a section on channels here:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/inappwebview-the-real-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-c6d52374209d

Then in your HTML/JavaScript, listen to full the screen event on your video object and send it to the JavaScript channel to be handled in Flutter app.